# Creating a system like a PowerPoint /Canva using html, css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, powerpoint

Is it possible to create a system using javascript, php, and css like a PowerPoint? Where you can add a text modify the text, change style, color etc.?

Comment: Check how  to ask question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to make a system like you have mentioned above using only HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Here are some examples for the systems that were made using JavaScript and some others:-

1. [Google Slides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Slides) - Made using JavaScript, CSS and HTML.
2. [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) - Made using TypeScript, JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.
3. [Wix](https://w3techs.com/sites/info/wix.com) - Made using JavaScript and Scala.

If you really want to do that, [JavaScript HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) will be useful for you in this task.

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Is there any available example for this activity?

Comment: Yes I have edited my answer just now. Have a look at it.

Comment: Always welcome :)